# I am getting following error while running my code

Tags: php, mysql

While I am running this code it showing me a following error:-

Column 'virtuemart_product_id' in where clause is ambiguous
Can anyone tell me how to resolve it.
Thank you.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('joom');
    $get=$_GET['virtuemart_product_id'];
    $get1=$_GET['virtuemart_category_id'];
    $sql="SELECT 
            btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id,
            btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_s_desc, 
            btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_desc, 
            btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_name, 
            btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices.product_price 
          FROM btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb 
          JOIN btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices ON
            btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id=btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices.virtuemart_product_id 
          WHERE virtuemart_product_id='$get' ";
    if($result=mysql_query($sql))
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo $row['product_price'];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo (mysql_error());
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Please shwo us the code/query, where the error occurs, otherwise we could just guess whats wrong...

Comment: may be because you are using join and in more than one table, column with same name exists.

Comment: if you can show query then one can suggest you some solution.

Comment: Good grace please lurn proper code syntaxing. put some tabs in there! also try to so the same for your query, php and mysql accept line breaks in a string just fine

Comment: but i have select that Column once in my query

Comment: The columns you select and the columns you use in the WHERE clause don't have any connection. You can use conditions with columns that aren't selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put table name (or alias) with column names in `where` clause which are common between tables you are joining.

Try below:

```
$sql="SELECT 
        btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id,
        btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_s_desc, 
        btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_desc, 
        btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_name, 
        btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices.product_price 
      FROM btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb 
      JOIN btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices ON
        btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id=btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices.virtuemart_product_id 
      WHERE  btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id='$get' ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i will use aliases from now

Answer (score 1):

In your `where` clause the property `virtuemart_product_id` is not identified unambiguously by a table name. Just use the table prefix there as well.

```sql
SELECT 
  prod.virtuemart_product_id,
  prod.product_s_desc, 
  prod.product_desc, 
  prod.product_name, 
  prices.product_price 
FROM btn9c_virtuemart_products_en_gb prod
JOIN btn9c_virtuemart_product_prices prices ON
  prod.virtuemart_product_id=prices.virtuemart_product_id 
WHERE prod.virtuemart_product_id='$get'
```

Btw use aliases for the tablenames. Saves a lot of typing and makes things more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the table name to the WHERE part of the query:

```
..."WHERE table_you_need.virtuemart_product_id='$get' ";
```